# Is there a way to combine reactive expressions in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm very new to reactivity, in the context of using R/Shiny as GIS..

Is it possible to have a reactive variable that will change if either of two different reactive expressions execute?

Basically the user can either manually create a data frame or upload one. Issue is, I have all the reactive expressions tied to the manual creation side ( customDF() ) and can't integrate the upload side.

In other words, I want the program to realize that a data frame has changed when I press either of two buttons (create data frame and upload). I've tried having either expression reassign a static variable but it broke the reactivity.

Here's what the button press method looks like:

```
customDF <- eventReactive(input$buildTable,{

    p <- getPoly()
    a <- attrib()

    for( i in 1:length(activeLayers)){
      word <- activeLayers[i]
      p[[word]] <- with(a, a[[word]][match(p$geoid, a$geoid)])
    }
    p 
  })

 # Method that uses it
 exportResult <- eventReactive(input$export, {        
    j <- customDF()
    writeSpatialShape(j, paste(repoLocation,input$layerName, sep=""))

    "Export successful"
  })

importResult <- eventReactive(input$selectImport, {
    # ?????? 
  })
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

import to file and select file?
adapted from: https://gist.github.com/jcheng5/9496297

**server.r**

```
#list of files
files <<- ("create data frame" = "create",
          "upload data frame" = "upload")

#cash results
getData <- memoise(function(file){
    if (!(file %in% files))
       stop("Unknown File")

     data<- as.data.frame(sprintf("path///to///file///location//%s.csv", file))

    data
    })

#reactive function
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  # Define a reactive expression for the document
  reactiveData <- reactive({
    # Change when the "update" button is pressed...
    input$update
    # ...but not for anything else
    isolate({
      withProgress(session, {
        setProgress(message = "Processing data...")
        getData(input$selection)
      })
    })
  })


#output as table or whatever
output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(
                     data <- as.data.frame(reactiveData())
                )
```

**ur.r**

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  progressInit(),

  # Application title
  headerPanel("data selection"),

  # Sidebar with a slider and selection inputs
  sidebarPanel(width = 5,
    selectInput("selection", "Choose a dataset:", 
                choices = files),
    actionButton("update", "Change"),

  ),

  # Show data
  mainPanel(
    DT::dataTableOutput("table")
  )
))
```